JQuery - How to append to element during each iteration of a loop
This is a question that seems to have been asked a number of times here by different people using a number of different coding languages, but no one seems to have come up with a clear definitive answer.
I have a div on my page with the id "showResultsHere":
<div id="showResultsHere"></div>
I then have a jQuery function which gets a page of 100 products, processes them and then moves onto the next page, and then the next page and so on until all pages have been processed.  I do this by having the jQuery function using a do/while loop, and in each loop it runs another function which makes an AJAX call to a php function which processes the page and returns the results.
Here is the code (which is currently just running a test php function):
function get_all_products( pageToProcess ){
    var pageResult;
    var totalPages;
    var updateMessage;
    do {
        pageResult = get_page_of_products( pageToProcess );
        totalPages = pageResult['page_count'];
        updateMessage = 'Page Processed = ' + pageResult['page'] + ' of ' + totalPages + '.';
        if(pageToProcess < totalPages){
            updateMessage += ' Next page = ' + pageResult['next_page'] + '.';
        }
        updateMessage += '<br />';
        console.log(updateMessage);
        jQuery("#showResultsHere").append(updateMessage);
        pageToProcess = pageResult['next_page'];
    }
    while (pageToProcess <= totalPages);
}

function get_page_of_products( pageToProcess )
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: <?php echo (json_encode(admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ))); ?>,
        data: "action=render_test&page=" + pageToProcess,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            pageResult = result;
        }
    });
    return pageResult;
}

And here is the php function that is being run at the url being called by the AJAX call:
function renderTest(){
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $next_page = $page + 1;
    $array = array('page'=>$page,'page_count'=>26,'next_page'=>$next_page);
    echo json_encode($array);
}

Now, you can see in the "get_all_products" function, I have these lines:
console.log(updateMessage);
jQuery("#showResultsHere").append(updateMessage);

The issue I'm having is that, while the "console.log(updateMessage);" line works perfectly and shows me the updated information during each loop of the function, the "jQuery("#showResultsHere").append(updateMessage);" line on the other hand does not;  instead, the "showResultsHere" div remains completely blank until every loop of the function is 100% complete and it then just spits all of the appends out at once at the very end.
I have tried moving the append to be within the AJAX call instead like so:
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: <?php echo (json_encode(admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ))); ?>,
    data: "action=render_test&page=" + pageToProcess,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(result){
        pageResult = result;
        jQuery("#showResultsHere").append('Blah blah blah...  Something something, yada yada.');
    }
});

But this makes absolutely no difference.
I really need a layperson like my client to be able to see the updated information on the page as it's running through each loop because they're not a developer and would know nothing about viewing the console window, etc.
Any ideas on now I can go about achieving this?
Thanks.

you need to learn how to deal with asynchronous methods properly, rather than using async: false.

Are there any error messages in the JavaScript console? Use the Network tab of DevTools to see the raw AJAX response, make sure it's valid JSON.

Hi Barmar.  I have to use "async:false" for this because when I'm not using a test function, the real function it executes is making an API call to fetch 100 products from an external supplier and it has 26 pages of results to iterate through.  If I make it asynchronous, the API freaks out (possibly thinks it's being hit by a DDOS attack) and over half the pages start return "500" errors.
But using async:false, no, there are no errors in the JavaScript console.

You can make them sequential while still keeping them async, perhaps by using promises and await.
